# What is "Low Pulse Trigger" and how to use it?

Tags: latching-relay

I picked up some of [these cheap Chinese Bistable relays](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1ch-5V-Latch-Relay-Module-Flip-Flop-Bistable-Self-locking-Trigger-Switch-Board/272480713213?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) and I am having trouble understanding how to get them hooked up. Do I put 5vdc + on VCC and 5vdc - on GND then use a low voltage pulse, such as 3.3vdc, to trigger it? I'm trying to use it with a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advertising page you linked pretty clearly indicates that you provide a Low (zero volts, or close to it) to operate or release the relay - one Low pulse will activeate the relay, the next Low pulse will release the relay.

It is not clear if the 3.3V from a Pi will be considered a Logic High by that module.

Comment: OK, let me wire it up real quick and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that actually worked. Took me a bit to get the timing right, but I got it to work like this. Marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wire 5VDC to VCC and your ground return to GND. Don't put -5V on GND otherwise you will have 10V across VCC to GND.

From the crude diagram it seems T is connected to some internal voltage, by placing a switch or button in between T and GND you can trigger a low pulse by connecting T to ground which will switch the relay.

Comment: I actually tried doing this and it did not work.